Raspberry pi pico circuit python specific folder show on file explorer
When I connect raspberry pi pico to the computer all files are shown, but i want to show only specific folders and files within. And I want to use circuit python and show only the sd card folder.
I tried to find help online but found nothing.

I don't know if it's possible to select specific folders/files/drives to show but have you check the documentation about 'Storage management' :

The storage provides storage management functionality such as mounting
and unmounting which is typically handled by the operating system
hosting Python. CircuitPython does not have an OS, so this module
provides this functionality directly.

https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/storage/index.html
Careful with the Pico storage, it's is very limited :
https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-storage
Mick
